# ChromeDriver logging when using Selenium Grid

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I want to save ChromeDriver logs when it runs on Selenium Grid on Windows. I can do it if I use this command to start the node

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.logfile=chromedriver.log -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -browser browserName=chrome
```

But the problem is every time a new instance of ChromeDriver starts, it overrides chromedriver.log.

I tried to use `chromedriver%time::=.%.log` and `chromedriver%%time::=.%%.log` as the filename to add time to it and avoid overriding. It works when I start ChromeDriver manually, but not when it's started by the Grid node.

I also tried to do it in the Java code of my Selenium tests, but I only found a solution for local Selenium and not Grid:

```
ChromeDriverService serv = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingAnyFreePort().withLogFile(
    new File("chromedriver" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".log")).build();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(serv);
```

Comment: there is the possibility to get driver logs from the webdriver interface. driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.DRIVER). if you need data from it. i know its not ur question but helps perhaps

Comment: @HenningLuther Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, `driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.DRIVER).getAll().size()` returns 0.

Comment: LoggingPreferences logPref = new LoggingPreferences();
logPref.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.ALL);    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPref); perhaps with it

Comment: @HenningLuther Yes, it works with this code, thanks! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Would be nice, glad i helped you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to grab the driver logs in a selenium grid the best way should be to use the selenium-log api. You don't have to care about at which node/browser your test is running, the api takes care.

First of all you tell the driver what level to log:

```
LoggingPreferences logPref = new LoggingPreferences(); 
logPref.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.ALL); 
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPref);
```

Than you grab the log entries like this:

```
driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.DRIVER).getAll()
```

where you will find all the log entries for your session.

Happy testing/coding.